# Deploying Dataflow in a CI pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I've written a streaming Google Dataflow pipeline in python using the beam SDK. There's documentation about how I run this locally and set the `-runner` flag to run it on Dataflow.

I'm now trying to automate the deployment of this to a CI pipeline (bitbucket pipelines but not really relevant). There is documentation on how to 'run' a pipeline, but not really 'deploy' it. The commands I've tested with look like:

```
python -m dataflow --runner "DataflowRunner" \
                   --jobName "<jobName>" \
                   --topic "<pub-sub-topic"" \
                   --project "<project>" \
                   --dataset "<dataset>" \
                   --worker_machine_type "n1-standard-2" \
                   --temp_location "gs://<bucket-name>/tmp/"
```

This will run the job, but because it's streaming it will never return. It also internally manages the packaging and pushing to a bucket. I know if I kill that process it keeps running, but setting that up on a CI server in a way where I can detect whether the process actually succeeded or I just killed it after some timeout is difficult.

This seems ridiculous and like I'm missing something obvious, but how do I package and run this module on dataflow in a way I can reliably know it deployed from a CI pipeline?

Comment: shouldn't it be deployed as a template ?

Answer (score 2):

So yes, it was something dumb.

Basically when you use the

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
```

syntax, under the hood it's calling [wait_until_finish](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.8.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/pipeline.py#L421). So the wait was being invoked without me realizing, causing it to hang around forever. Refactoring to remove the context manager fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [jamielennox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53165083/15649).

When on the direct runner on your local development environment, you want to see the pipeline running indefinitely; perhaps only to manually cancel with Ctrl-C after a while.

When deploying the pipeline to run on GCP's Dataflow, you want your script to deploy the job and end.

```
runner_name = pipeline_options.get_all_options().get('runner')

if runner_name == 'DirectRunner':
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        _my_setup_pipeline(config, pipeline, subscription_full_name)

elif runner_name == 'DataflowRunner':
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    _my_setup_pipeline(config, pipeline, subscription_full_name)
    pipeline.run()

else:
    raise Exception(f'Unknown runner: {runner_name}')
```